# bytes value while initialising struct

Tags: solidity, struct

```
struct Proposal{
    uint32 id;
    string text;
    bytes docs;
    bool selected;
    uint expectedBudget;
    address submitter;
}



// _text and _expectedBudget already define.

Proposal proposal = Proposal({
                      id:getId(),
                      text:_text,
                      docs:<what_should_I_use_here>,
                      selected:false,
                      expectedBudget:_expectedBudget,
                      submitter: msg.sender
                    })
```

I want to set something like null for `docs`. what to use in solidity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work

```
Proposal proposal = Proposal({
                  id:getId(),
                  text:_text,
                  docs:'',
                  selected:false,
                  expectedBudget:_expectedBudget,
                  submitter: msg.sender
                })
```

The value of docs will be `0x`.

That being said, consider using `bytes` with a fixed length like `bytes32`, it is much cheaper.

See the [official documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#dynamically-sized-byte-array) for more precision.